# I get Metadata.framework error when I try to import an image

Tags: swift, image, macos, cocoa, import

I've got the following message in Xcode's Debug Area after importing an image in my app:

```
"[21950:1148196] Metadata.framework [Error]: couldn't get the client port".
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Here's my code for uploading a picture:

```
@IBAction func importButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let uploadFile: NSOpenPanel = NSOpenPanel()

    uploadFile.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    uploadFile.canChooseFiles = true
    uploadFile.canChooseDirectories = false

    uploadFile.runModal()

    let chosenPicture = uploadFile.URL

        if(chosenPicture != nil) {

            let pictureImport = NSImage(contentsOfURL: chosenPicture!)
            imageWell.image = pictureImport
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this error message because I have Spotlight indexing disabled (so apps' and images' metadata is inaccessible).

After turning Spotlight automatic indexing ON the error message

```
"Metadata.framework [Error]: couldn't get the client port"
```

in Xcode's Debug Area disappears.